# How to find mapping of OData edm model type to clr type?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

My data layer doesn't expose IQueryable. Still I want to be able to sort data. My API has such capability but I need to identify what needs to be sorted. Say I configured the model, e.g.:

```
ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Airline>("Airlines");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<FlightLeg>("Legs");
```

Now in controller I'm able to get OdataQueryOptions and find out on what edm model types/properties sorting is requested. What I need to accomplish is to get PropertyInfo of the property in the CLR type that was used for configuration, e.g. Airline.PlaneModel.

I struggle to get that metadata through the API but without success. Please, help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code snippet in a controller:

```
        //using Microsoft.Data.Edm
        IEdmModel edmModel = Request.ODataProperties().Model;
        ClrTypeAnnotation annotation = edmModel.GetAnnotationValue<ClrTypeAnnotation>(edmSchemaType);
        if (annotation != null)
        {
            return annotation.ClrType;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Tan. Where do you get documentation for these capabilities?

Comment: this works great, but what if I have a collection of entities and I need the underlying type? where could I find some documentation for this?